# Jvectormap 1.2.2 color issue

Tags: jquery, dictionary, colors, country, jvectormap

I am using the latest Jvectormap (1.2.2) but can't find any examples of **setting all the country colors**. I believe in the previous version it was simply "color:", but now this has been discontinued?

The code below works but the color part doesn't. I use a white background on my site so want **all the countries to have a different color by default.**

```
 <script>
  $(function(){
        $('#world-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    color: '#000000',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        series: {
       regions: [{
            values: {
                IN:'#33250B',
                US:'#003366'
        }
       }]
         }
     })
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

i am not quiet sure what you mean, but to set all the countries colors you could use:

```
var regionStyling = {initial: {fill: '#128da7'},hover: {fill: "#A0D1DC"}};

jQuery('#world-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    regionStyle:regionStyling,
    backgroundColor: '#383f47',
    series: {regions: [{values: {},attribute: 'fill'}]}
});
```

this works for me, also if you want to specify per country you could use:

```
 jQuery('#world-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    backgroundColor: '#383f47',
    series: {regions: [{values: {"US" : "#000"},attribute: 'fill'}]}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the 1.x.x branch of jVectorMap desired functionality could be achieved by using `regionStyle` configuration parameter. See more in the documentation [here](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/).

Answer (score 0):

To set the default color for all regions, set `regionStyle.default.fill`.

Here's your code with that change:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#world-map').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill_en',
            regionStyle: { initial: { fill: '#000000' } },  //Changed this line
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            series: {
                regions: [{
                    values: {
                        IN:'#33250B',
                        US:'#003366'
                    }
                }]
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```